# Calculating dates expecting double

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to simply subtract two dates. Probably this is a messy way of doing it. It says it cannot convert to double even though.

```
DateTime daysPlus14days = _dal.getOptinDate(new Guid(_myuser.id.ToString())).AddDays(14);
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime timeLeft = (daysPlus14days - currentDate).TotalDays
```

This just basically goes to db and gets me the date they created there account. Its just to work out how many days left they have 14 days to click a button other wise it will vanish.

```
public DateTime getOptinDate(Guid id)
{
    var q = _dal.portalEntities.tblPortalUsers.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    return (DateTime)q.optinDateStart;          
}
```

Comment: Why don`t you use TimeSpan?

Comment: refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx; TimeSpan t;t.TotalDays gives the total no of days.

Comment: Also, be aware of local time vs. UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change this line:

```
double timeLeft = (daysPlus14days - currentDate).TotalDays;
```

`TotalDays` returns double and not `DateTime`

Comment: I that worked it gave me 12.5 days though for date but its ment to be 13.5 if date was only yesterday whihc is weird im storing date in db as  2016-07-07 which is i thought should be 13 but i persume cause its near 12 pm its considering it half a day

Comment: @david Try `daysPlus14days.Date` then.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx,

```
System.DateTime date1 = new System.DateTime(1996, 6, 3, 22, 15, 0);
System.DateTime date2 = new System.DateTime(1996, 12, 6, 13, 2, 0);
System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);
double totaldays = diff1.TotalDays;
```